# Proc Phreg Baseline Statement Equivalent in R

Tags: r, sas, survival-analysis, survival

Is there a way to generate a table similar to the output of the baseline statement in SAS' proc phreg. Specifically, I want baseline harzards and survival probabilities at several time points for all combinations of the covariate set.

Comment: It may help to include your SAS code and an example of the output since an R user would not know what that looks like.

Comment: You are expected to have done some searching before posting question on SO. You are also expected to add enough detail to support a coding answer. Missing in the current vers are any data or code or even an example table. If you use the [edit] facilities to improve your question, it will improve the odds of getting an a statisfactory answer. Please do the Tour and see pages in the Help Center for a better understanding of what makes a "good question".

Comment: If you scroll down about halfway this page has what you want. https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/09/25/survival-analysis-with-r/